# Is there any way to play corrupted .MOV video file

Tags: video

Today I recorded presentation I gave to my development team, part of this recording was screencast. Right after I finished, screen capturing tool that I used collapsed and I was left with [corrupted .MOV file (160Mb)](http://yadi.sk/d/pv2PMVjc02Los)

Here is header:

```
0000000      0000    1400    7466    7079    7471    2020    0000    0000
0000020      7471    2020    0000    0800    6977    6564    0000    0000
0000040      646d    7461    2021    4003    1c68    4e21    3bff    785a
0000060      d8ac    c326    6d06    bf0e    5c5d    0010    0000    2000
0000100      4c45    9987    9691    8948    9b15    dbfd    000e    0000
0000120      c700    c774    7541    a2c6    3fd5    8a92    7880    677d
0000140      ed57    87ff    b783    00ae    7dfc    7e6f    78f0    fbfe
0000160      0678    6839    eefb    230f    8ca7    0100    2387    977e
0000200      a44f    61e5    f5d5    073e    1d2f    88b7    0400    4bd7
0000220      0e3d    ef59    faef    d1f3    808d    6f00    dd67    1d37
```

Is it corrupted?
Is there any way to play such file?

I can not recapture my talk so I really hope you could help me.

Comment: I've had similar things happen with important videos, which I was a rare problem with photobooth. Yes I know, photobooth. But I had no luck fixing the file that was corrupted even even trying many different options. Hope someone knows though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found tiny tools called [recover_mp4](http://slydiman.narod.ru/rus/mmedia/recover_mp4.htm) , emailed it's author who modified it to conform my case. iShowYou suppor has not answer me yet.

There is also cool online tool called [mp4repair](http://mp4repair.org/pwt6/preview.html) that is frontend to video repair service.

Answer (score 1):

Trying using a program called VLC, a lot of times it will play corrupt video clips but it may crash/and or stop playing around corrupt portion

Comment: I tried it with the file the OP linked to.  No go with VLC v2.0.3.

Comment: I thought about giving an answer like this, but with stuff I had recorded from screencapturing or from a webcam, VLC has not worked

Comment: @josh I had not seen that he actually linked the file, I will download and play around with it...travis, the problem with a lot and most screen capture software and photobooth is the frame rate is not a standered frame rate, all you have to do is try and open it in a software that only accepts legal frame rates and it could crash and currupt the file, which is why I tell people to stay away from cheap versions of these softwares and use quicktime webcam recording ect.  but if the file does not open with VLC you very well may be out of luck unfortunately